# Depth Image Ball detection

Tags: python, opencv, object-detection, contour, ros

I am working with an Asus xtion pro live cam. And I am actually using the depth image to detect a ball. More specific with the openni2 ros package I subscribe to the /camera/depth_registered/image topic.

On the picture below you can see 2 Balls however only one of them is detected
 with the opencv find contours algorithm ....

1) Any ideas why only one ball is detected with find contours?

2)Does anyone know if the depth registered value like 71 directly means the distance is 0.71 meters? Or how do I convert the gray value to a distance in meters?

3) If anyone knows some nice improvements on the code please comment :) Thanks!

Here is my current python / opencv2 example code:

The input image can be found here: [image]

Start the code with **python depth_detection.py 2_balls.jpg**

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import sys

print "{}  {}".format("Analyze this file: ", sys.argv[1])

im = cv2.imread(sys.argv[1])
imgray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.imshow('image',imgray)
cv2.waitKey(50)
# Thresholding - delete all points outside 60cm - 150cm
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(imgray, 60, 150, 0)
cv2.imshow('thresh',thresh)
cv2.waitKey(50)

kernel = np.ones((7,7),np.uint8)
erosion = cv2.erode(thresh, kernel, iterations = 4)
dilation = cv2.dilate(erosion, kernel, iterations = 4)
cv2.imshow('dilation', dilation)
cv2.waitKey(50)


contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(dilation, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
print len(contours)
cv2.drawContours(im, contours, -1, (255,255,0), 3)
cv2.imshow('contours',im)
cv2.waitKey(50)

(x,y),radius = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(contours[8])
center = (int(x),int(y))
px = im[x, y]
print "Center Position in pixel: {} distance_value: {}".format(center, px)
radius = int(radius)
cv2.circle(im,center,radius,(255,0,0),2)
cv2.circle(im,center,1,(255,0,255),2)
cv2.imshow('result',im)
cv2.waitKey(5000)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

PS: The second ball I would like to detect lies directly behind the first detected ball :)

The current result:
[image: Only one ball detected :(]

Comment: have a look at the threshold image and the preprocessed image before you start contour detection. Probably the second ball and the table/flloor are either completely in foregorund or completely in background. The other ball probably is only detected because the border does not provide any depth values, so there are hard edges. You should try to work on the point cloud instead of the raw depth map. I would suggest a ransac algorithm to detect (half-) spheres.

Comment: @Micka The other ball is bigger and thus not that far away. That is why it is more dark I guess .... and therefore detected.  I do not want to use the point cloud of the raw depth map cause it is much more slowly .....                                        Do you have any example code on that ransac algorithm and do you know how to configure some parameters so that opencv detects the edges of the second ball as well?

Comment: the black color means that there is no depth value available for that pixel. If you want to work on the raw depth map you'll have to use some smart interpretation of pixel values to use image processing here. If you think about what thresholding is, you probably should not threshold depth values, unless you only want to find objects of some minimum/maximum distance to the sensor. You could give gradient based approaches like edge detection a chance since there is some kind of depth-edge between different objects.

Comment: Thanks for the hint on black color means no depth value. Do you know where I can find the gray to distance value calculation? e.g. does a grey value of 80 mean that the distance to the camera for this pixel is 80 cm?   I use a asus xtion pro live cam....

Comment: sorry, no idea for that camera and driver. I once used kinect and got the distance values directly from the used library (openni) in mm. But it's some good time ago.

Comment: ah, in your code you loaded the images from disk. How did you capture and save them? Afaik, typically depth images are type single channel unsigned 16 bit. Did you scale them before writing them? Did you save with 16 bit precision? OpenCV loads images with 8 bit precision by default, even if they are saved as 16 bit, you'll need appropriate flags for imread.